# How to print in template something when queryset build with union() changes?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have two queryset: q1 and q2. I make a union of them with

```
q1.union(q2)
```

Now, when I print in template the queryset with a for loop, how can I print something between the two querysets? Something like:

**Featured results**
(q1 forloop)

**Other results**
(q2 forloop)

Why I thought to use union instead of separated querysets? Because I want only one pagination for both

Thank you

Comment: What are the types / models of the `Featured results` and the `Other results` - are you sure they can't be retrieved in a single queryset with a field/flag to differentiate them?

Comment: In the model I have a method that tells me if an object should be in q1 or q2, but the problem is that I have to apply different filters for q1 and q2